# SQL Server 2012: How to calculate Quarterly Average with only values from the first of each month

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE Portfolio.DailyNAV
(
Date date NOT NULL,
NAV int NOT NULL,
)
GO
```

The date column has the daily business day starting from '2015-02-02' and the NAV column has that day's total asset value. I want to get the average NAV for a quarter. For this example, let's assume I want to get it for the 2nd Quarter of 2016. My code is now:

```
Select AVG(NAV) As AvgNAV
FROM Portfolio.DailyNAV
WHERE year(Date) = '2016' AND DATEPART(QUARTER,Date) = '2'
GO
```

The problem I am facing is that this code calculates the daily average for the quarter but Average NAV should be calculated only using the first business date of each month for that quarter. So for 2016 Q2, the Average NAV should be the average from 2016-04-01, 2016-05-02 (the 1st was not a work day) and 2016-06-01. I don't want to simply change my WHERE clause and use those dates because at I want to make a stored procedure where the user can get the average NAV by putting in the Year and Quarter.

Thanks.

Comment: So you want to include days which fall outside of your QUARTER = 2 clause?

Comment: Hi, no I am including the days that fall within the quarter = 2 clause but the average should be calculated only using the first business date of each month for that quarter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),[Date],112)
                                    ORDER BY [Date])
    FROM Portfolio.DailyNAV
    WHERE YEAR([Date]) = 2016 
    AND DATEPART(QUARTER,[Date]) = 2
    AND NAV IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT AVG(NAV) AvgNAV
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Comment: Hi, this gives me the same result as my my code i.e. it's taking the daily average instead of only the first record for each month in that quarter

Comment: @MilesToGoBeforeISleep Yes, of course, I forgot a condition. Updated my answer now

Comment: Thanks. This works. Can you please explain what RN, Row_Number, OVER and PARTITION is doing? I am new at this and that particular line of coding isn't something I've come across before.

Comment: Actually I think I figured it out. You added a row number to each row which resets every month. Brilliant. Thanks again.

Comment: `RN = ` is just giving a column alias to that calculation. And for `ROW_NUMBER`, [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/.../ms186734.aspx) is a link to the documentation

Comment: @MilesToGoBeforeISleep yeah, that's exactly what it's doing